# Sequelize - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (on a perfectly fine adress)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to put in production a site I made with **Angular** and **Express/Sequelize**, but always have Sequelize errors :

- It works perfectly fine in local with WAMP, I can reach my local database and it's all good.
- When I'm trying to use my OVH database (that I got with my hosting plan), I have the following errors :

```js
HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dodobwtdodob.mysql.db
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:120:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
    at async C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
    at async C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26        
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:225:12)
    at async Function.sync (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1300:5)
    at async Sequelize.sync (C:\Users\Dorian\Desktop\Développement Web\Mes sites\capitales\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:793:35) {
  parent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dodobwtdodob.mysql.db
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'dodobwtdodob.mysql.db',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dodobwtdodob.mysql.db
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'dodobwtdodob.mysql.db',
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

I don't understand because I've always used the same config, it works fine when I'm using a PHP PDO object on other projects for example. It doesn't work either on my OVH VPS, where I'm getting connection refused error (even if I had to look at all the tutorials on the net), but that's another problem.

Here is my **db.config.js** :

```js
module.exports = {
    HOST: "dodobwtdodob.mysql.db",
    USER: "dodobwtdodob",
    PASSWORD: "secretpassword",
    DB: "dodobwtdodob",
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    },
    port:3306
  };
```

And here a part of my **index.js** :

```js
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  port: dbConfig.port,
  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});
```

Comment: check you db URL,  username and password

Comment: they are all good

Answer (score 0):

Please change hostname "dodobwtdodob.mysql.db" to ipAddress(host address).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).